# Update an existing item in a ChatModel dictionary from a Firestore snapshot

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show an overview in a TableView of all existing chats (Name, LastMessage) for a specific user.

Right now, I append a new item in my TableView, which is obviously wrong, instead I want to update the existing item by it's key "ChatId"

This is my Model:

```
class ChatModel {

var chatOwnerId: String?
var chatPartnerId: String?
var createdDate: Timestamp?
var chatId: String?
var lastMessage: String?
var lastMessageDate: Timestamp?

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    chatOwnerId = dictionary["chatOwnerId"] as? String
    chatPartnerId = dictionary["chatPartnerId"] as? String
    createdDate = dictionary["createdDate"] as? Timestamp
    chatId = dictionary["chatId"] as? String
    lastMessage = dictionary["lastMessage"] as? String
    lastMessageDate = dictionary["lastMessageDate"] as? Timestamp
    }
}
```

How I add the data to my model:

```
func loadChatOverviewNew(currentUser: String) {
    ChatApi.shared.observeChatOverviewNew(currentUser: currentUser) { (chatOverview) in
        self.chats.insert(chatOverview, at: 0)            
        self.chatTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

How can I update my "chats" when I receive a new snapshot, instead of appending / inserting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update an existing item, find that item in the array by calling ``, and then update it.

Something like:

```
ChatApi.shared.observeChatOverviewNew(currentUser: currentUser) { (chatOverview) in
    if let index = self.chats.firstIndex(where: { $0.chatId == chatOverview.chatId }) {
        self.chats[index] = chatOverview
    }
    else {
        self.chats.insert(chatOverview, at: 0)            
    }
    self.chatTableView.reloadData()
}
```